# не вызывается QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint при изменении размера колонки в QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

Когда мышкой увеличиваю размер столбца, то paint отрабатывает корректно и длинная строка разворачивается в одну линию, но высота строки остается прежняя - вызов метода sizeHint при изменении размера не происходит и отображается пустота - как это исправить.
h:

```cpp
#include "QMainWindow"
#include "QTreeWidget"
#include "QTreeWidgetItem"
#include "QStyledItemDelegate"
#include "QLineEdit"
#include "QPainter"

class PropertyItem;
class Properties: public QTreeWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:

public:
    Properties();
    ~Properties() {}
    PropertyItem* add_property(const QString& name);
};
class PropertyItem: public QTreeWidgetItem {
    Properties* m_properties;
    QString m_name;
public:
    PropertyItem(Properties* treeWidget);
    PropertyItem();//child
    ~PropertyItem() {}
    PropertyItem* add_property_str(const QString& name);
public:
    const QString& getName() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const QString &name) { m_name = name; }
    void setProperties(Properties* properties) { m_properties = properties; }
};
class PropertyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PropertyDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override;
private:
    Properties *m_tree;
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(PropertyDelegate)
};
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Properties *m_properties;
    PropertyDelegate *m_propertyDelegate;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
</code></pre>
cpp:
<pre><code>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "QHeaderView"
Properties::Properties(): QTreeWidget() {
    setColumnCount(2);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    PropertyItem* twi = new PropertyItem(this);
    twi->setText(0, "1");
    twi->setText(0, "2");
    addTopLevelItem(twi);
    resizeColumnToContents(0);
    resizeColumnToContents(1);
    header()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Interactive);
}
PropertyItem* Properties::add_property(const QString& name) {
    PropertyItem* pi = new PropertyItem(this);
    pi->setName(name);
    return pi;
}
PropertyItem::PropertyItem(Properties* treeWidget) : QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget), m_properties(treeWidget) {
    setFlags(flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
}
PropertyItem::PropertyItem() : QTreeWidgetItem(), m_properties(nullptr) {
    setFlags(flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
}
PropertyItem* PropertyItem::add_property_str(const QString& name) {
    PropertyItem* pi = new PropertyItem();
    pi->setProperties(m_properties);
    addChild(pi);
    pi->setName(name);
    return pi;
}
PropertyDelegate::PropertyDelegate(QObject* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
    m_tree = static_cast<Properties*>(parent);
}
void PropertyDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &) const {
    QLineEdit* edt = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    edt->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
QWidget *PropertyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QWidget* editWidget = nullptr;
    if (index.column() != 0) {
        editWidget = new QLineEdit(parent);
    }
    return editWidget;
}
void PropertyDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    if (index.column() != 0) {
        PropertyItem* item = static_cast<PropertyItem*>(m_tree->itemFromIndex(index));
        if (item) {
            QString str(item->getName());
            QLineEdit* lineEdit = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
            lineEdit->setText(str);
        }
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
    }
}
void PropertyDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel*, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    PropertyItem* item = static_cast<PropertyItem*>(m_tree->itemFromIndex(index));
    if (item) {
        QLineEdit* lineEdit = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        QString qstr = lineEdit->text();
        item->setName(qstr);
    }
}
void PropertyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    Q_ASSERT(index.isValid());
    PropertyItem* item = static_cast<PropertyItem*>(m_tree->itemFromIndex(index));
    if(item) {
        QString str = item->getName();
        painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::TextWordWrap, str);
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
QSize PropertyDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const {
    PropertyItem* item = dynamic_cast<PropertyItem*>(m_tree->itemFromIndex(index));
    QString str = item->getName();
    QSize size = option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(option.rect, Qt::TextWordWrap, str).size();
    qDebug() << "sizeHint " << index.column() << size << str;
    return size;
}
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {
    m_properties = new Properties();
    m_propertyDelegate = new PropertyDelegate(m_properties);
    m_properties->setItemDelegate(m_propertyDelegate);
    m_properties->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Raised);
    m_properties->viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    m_properties->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked
            | QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
    setCentralWidget(m_properties);

    PropertyItem* property = m_properties->add_property("1name long");
    property->add_property_str("second1 second1");

    property = m_properties->add_property("2name long");
    property->add_property_str("second2 second2");

    property = m_properties->add_property("3name long");
    property->add_property_str("second3 second3");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для оповещения `view` о том, что изменился `sizeHint` можно использовать сигнал `QAbstractItemDelegate::sizeHintChanged(const QModelIndex &index)`. Например:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {
    m_properties = new Properties();
    m_propertyDelegate = new PropertyDelegate(m_properties);
    m_properties->setItemDelegate(m_propertyDelegate);

    connect(m_properties->header(), &QHeaderView::sectionResized, m_properties, &Properties::sectionResized);

    //...
}

void PropertyDelegate::emitSizeHintChanged(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    emit sizeHintChanged(index);
}

void Properties::sectionResized()
{
    static_cast<PropertyDelegate *>(itemDelegate())->emitSizeHintChanged(selectionModel()->currentIndex());
}
```

Таким образом при изменении размера хедера `view` будет вызывать `sizeHint` делегата.

Однако для вашей цели этого не достаточно. В `PropertyDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const` передаётся `option`, которая содержит ненастоящий `option.rect`. Можно производить подсчёт так:

```
QSize PropertyDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const {
    PropertyItem* item = dynamic_cast<PropertyItem*>(m_tree->itemFromIndex(index));
    QString str = item->getName();
    int indent = 0; //Учёт декоративного отступа
    // по аналогии с QTreeView::visualRect (qtreeview.cpp)
    if (m_tree->layoutDirection() == Qt::LeftToRight && logicalIndexForTree() == index.column()) {
        //Отступ есть только на индексе древа
        //В случае размещения слева направо
        indent = itemLevelCount(index) * m_tree->indentation();
    }
    QSize size = option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(0,0, m_tree->header()->sectionSize(index.column()) - indent, 0, Qt::TextWordWrap, str).size();
    return size;
}

int PropertyDelegate::logicalIndexForTree() const
{
    int index = m_tree->treePosition();
    if (index < 0)
        index = m_tree->header()->logicalIndex(0);
    return index;
}

//Подсчёт уровня расположения элемента в древе. Возможно есть способ проще?
int PropertyDelegate::itemLevelCount(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    int level = 0;
    QModelIndex temp = index;
    QModelIndex root = m_tree->rootIndex();
    do {
        temp = temp.parent();
        level++;
    } while (temp != root);
    if (!m_tree->rootIsDecorated()) level--;
    return level;
}
```

По итогу в объявление `PropertyDelegate` было добавлено:

```
private:
    int itemLevelCount(const QModelIndex& index) const;
    int logicalIndexForTree() const;
public:
    void emitSizeHintChanged(const QModelIndex& index);
```

В `Properties`:

```
public slots:
    void sectionResized();
```

Comment: Собрал - работает. Не понял только почему "содержит ненастоящий option.rect". И connect сделал внутри конструктора Properties.

Comment: У меня на Qt5.10 в исходниках `options` создаётся методом, где `rect = Rect()`. Например, перед вызовом `paint` он заполняется, но перед вызовом `sizeHint` он `option.rect.setWidth(-1); // Hack to speed up the function`. Это логично т.к. мы ещё не знаем размеры. У вас всё нормально, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да - все нормально - спасибо.